# Swift find if a String.Index is undefined

Tags: swift

I want to find if my variable midPoint is undefined. Unfortunately the following will not compile

```
let midPoint : String.Index
if (typeof midPoint === "undefined" )
    {print ("undefined")}
```

> typeof

does not work, and neither does

> type

Comment: do you mean `if midPoint == nil`?

Comment: Swift is not JavaScript, why are you trying to use the same syntax and methods? There's no type `undefined` in Swift, the compiler won't let you leave any values uninitialised, so there'd be no point in having an `undefined` type.

Comment: @meggar Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Yet midPoint is undefined before I have given it a value.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as undefined in Swift. Every property must have a value by the time of initialisation. If you __define__ a property without giving it an initial value, it must get a value in the initialiser of the type holding the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have there is Javascript, that's not going to compile. Swift doesn't have `undefined`. What Swift does have are Optionals. (Indicated by the `?` behind the type). So the following code is approximately what you were doing:

```
let midPoint: String.Index? = nil
if midPoint == nil {
  print ("midPoint is nil")
}
```

Swift will not allow you to use an undefined value, so midPoint has to be set to `nil` (or a value).

If the value that you are getting is not an options, you will not have to test for `nil`, because it's not possible to be `nil`. For instance:

```
let index = "Hello world".endIndex
```

Here, `endIndex` is of type `String.Index`, so you know there will always be a value.

```
let index = "Hello world".firstIndex(of "t")
```

Here you will HAVE to 'check' the value (unwrap it) before using, because the return type `String.Index?`, an optional. You do that like this:

```
if let index = index {
   // you can use index here
}
```